# Renaming images in a multi-file upload project to correspond with number of images selected

Tags: php, html, session, file-upload, session-variables

I'm dealing with a few issues regarding multiple file uploads. My project deals with a form the user inputs multiple images that save to a database, but first temporarily stores the images in a directory to show a preview of sorts.  In my class that deals with the uploading of the image I am trying to rename the images as seen below.

If I upload one image at a time, the previews work and each image is unique with a unique name. However if when I click the upload button and hold control while selecting images ie select multiple images a a time, they all save as the same name and the images that preview show duplicate images of whatever first image I selected.

**How do I go about adding like a number corresponding to that sessions amount of pics uploaded like'name-of-image-1.jpg' , 'name-of-image-2.jpg', etc etc?**

```
protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,$index = null, $content_range = null)     
{
    $file = new \stdClass();
    $file->name = $this->generate_unique_filename($name);   
    ... //more code
}


protected function generate_unique_filename($filename = "")
{

    $extension = "";
    if ( $filename != "" )
    {
        $extension = pathinfo($filename , PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if ( $extension != "" )
        {
            $extension = "." . $extension;
        }
    }
    $filename = getmypid() . '_'.time();

    return $filename;
}
```

Comment: FYI , its better to show preview using jQuery instead of uploading image and then show preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case when you upload files,a single process id is handling all requests ,So every image gets the same name i.e. same (process id + time).

**$filename = getmypid() . '_'.time();**    (better use microtime())

You can  do something like this to rename the file with hyphen added( the numbers added would be 0,1,2 etc).

//html

```
<input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

//php

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) 

       {
          $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

      if ($tmpFilePath != "")
        {

          $oldFile= $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];
          $old_name=pathinfo($oldFile);
          $add_new_name = 'new-image-'.$i.'.'.$old_name['extension'];

/* or use   $add_new_name = microtime().'-'.$i.'.'.$old_name['extension'];*/

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, "./youruploadfolder/".$add_new_name))
  { 
       //rest of the code here

        }
      }
    }
```

set the second parameter of move_uploaded_file what you like (**your upload folder name**).